# Is this integration valid

Tags: integration, substitution

Is this a valid manoeuvre, or does it need further validation?

$$\dfrac{\pi}{4}=\int_0^1 (1-x^2)^{1/2}dx$$
$$=\int_0^1 e^{\ln{(1-x^2)^{1/2}}}dx$$
$$=\int_0^1 e^{\frac12\ln{(1-x^2)}}dx$$

We can then turn the $\ln$ into a power series, and pass this to $e$ as $e^X$ to further expand into another power series, which we can then integrate to give a power series for $\pi/4$.

Comment: Seems ok to me. May I know how do you want to use of such manipulation?

Comment: power series are (relatively) easy to integrate

Comment: @Hrodelbert; true, fixed

Comment: integrate the exponential of a power series usually lead you nowhere. why not integrate this by changing variable to $x = \sin\theta$?

Comment: @achillehui; good idea!

Comment: For that matter, you can develop a power series for the original function

Comment: "We can then turn the ln into a power series, and pass this to e." Turn the ln into a power series: yes. Pass this to e: basically undoable.

Comment: Aside from undoable, introducing a logarithm is hardly correct if you have to evaluate it at the extreme of the interval of integration $x=1$, which results in $\ln 0$.

Comment: @MiguelAtencia; the problem dissipates before it comes to that

Comment: If your goal is to evaluate this integral, note that you are looking at the area of the unit circle in the first quadrant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substitution as mentioned by @achille, or you can integrate by parts, setting:
$$u=\sqrt{1-x^2}, \;\mathrm d\mkern1mu v=\mathrm d\mkern1mu x,\enspace\text{whence}\enspace \mathrm d\mkern1mu u=-\frac{x\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}},\;v=x.$$
The formula yields:
\begin{align*}\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x & =x\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\biggl\rvert_0^1+\int_0^1\frac{x^2\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\int_0^1\frac{(x^2-1)\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm d\mkern1mu x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\
&=-\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x +\arcsin x\,\biggl\rvert_0^1=-\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x + \frac\pi2,
\end{align*}
whence the result.

Comment: Why this downvote?

Comment: because your argument is entirely circular - it proves nothing we don't already know

Comment: Oh! so you  absolutely want to do it with power series? Btw, I  couldn't deduce what you know from your question.

Comment: the downvote is ridiculous ...